# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE returns empty set in JPA (Eclipselink & Google CloudSQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, google-cloud-sql

I'm developing JPA application using Eclipselink and Google CloudSQL, but `getResultList` with statement "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" sometimes returns empty set.

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE` (
  `a` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `b` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `c` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL ,
  `d` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL ,
  `e` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL ,
  `f` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL ,
  `g` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`b`),
  KEY `INDEX_1` (`b`,`a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This table has these records.

```
+-----+------+---
| a   | b    | 
+-----+------+---
| aaa | bbb  | 
| ccc | ddd  |  .......
| eee | fff  | 
+-----+------+---
```

Code

```
EntityManagerFactory instance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");
EntityManager em = instance.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

tx.begin();

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE (a = ? AND b = ?) OR (a = ? AND b = ?) OR (a = ? AND b = ?) FOR UPDATE", MyTableClass.class);
q.setParameter(1, "aaa");
q.setParameter(2, "bbb");
q.setParameter(3, "ccc");
q.setParameter(4, "ddd");
q.setParameter(5, "eee");
q.setParameter(6, "fff");

List<MyTableClass> list = q.getResultList(); 

tx.commit();
```

But sometimes list.size() becomes 0.

I can't find why this happen.
If two threads execute above code simultaneously, my expectation is that one thread is blocked until another thread is commited or one thread throws exception if lock timeout.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723981/mysql-select-for-update-returns-empty-set-even-though-a-row-exists) question, but I don't modify column `a` and `b`.

What is the reason of this issue, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: perhaps you want to put parentheses (brackets) around the parts "(a = ? and b = ?)" so the precedence of OR and AND are clear ...

Comment: I modified my post. But I think this does not affect behavior.

Comment: it affects which rows would match the WHERE clause

Comment: Make a simple test case where you use two EntityManagers that both try to select for update the same rows and see if you can reproduce it reliably.  This is a native query though, so it isn't really a JPA issue.  Check your driver and database documentation/setup to see if you have configured something to ignore locked rows somehow - something like setting it to use READPAST